# Can't create directory via asmx web service

Tags: web-services, asmx

I am trying to create a directory and then write to it via an asmx web service.  It works fine on my dev pc, but when I publish the service to the server, I keep getting access denied errors.  I have gone in to IIS and made sure the service has write privileges.  I also gave write access to all users, but am still getting the same error.  Any suggestions?

**Additional info**
Well, I solved the problem.  When I called

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
```

it worked fine on my development box but blew up on the server. I needed to use

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(directoryName));
```

which worked fine on both.

Comment: What sort of exception are you getting?

Comment: What is the server environment? 2003? 2008? Apache+mod_mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone searching.  The following code did the trick:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(directoryName));
```

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is to make sure the IIS user account has access to the directory.

Next I would say double check your code.  Are you trying to write to a directory that isn't there?  Did you forget to change a config setting.

99% when I have had the same issues, it is usually a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an access denied error, then it's an access denied error, period. It doesn't matter that it's happening from a web service. Diagnose it as you would diagnose any other access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give "Network Service" write permission for that directory. Please check which OS you are useing also. It may need a different account.