# Image load timeout in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, browser, timeout

I have a page for an internal app that displays document images streamed from a document storage system using a web service.  The problem I am having is that when a user does their search they may get hundreds of hits, which I have to display on one large page so they can print them all. This works fine in Firefox, but in IE it stops loading the images after a while so I get a hundred or so displayed and the rest just have the broken image symbol. Is there a setting somewhere that I can change this timeout?

Comment: @Niklas - aren't bounties automatically awarded if no answer is accepted?

Comment: Hm, I actually don't know? Would be great if it worked like that.

Comment: @Niklas - from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work : "At the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, eligible answers can be automatically awarded half the bounty amount."

Comment: Thanks! I still hope Kevin will learn to accept more questions though...

Comment: @Kevin - No. But if you were able to find an answer, like you did in this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868044/cant-create-directory-via-asmx-web-service ), you can post your solution as an answer to the question, and then accept your own answer. This is actually encouraged, and is preferable to editing the question and putting the solution in there like you did.

Comment: @Kevin & Joshua Carmody: Better to post the solution in the question as to tell no one. OK, it's not the preferred way, but there are more then enough out there that just post nothing!

Answer (score 10):

If the issue is indeed a timeout, you might be able to work around it by using a "lazy load" script and adding new images to the document only after existing images have loaded.

There are a lot of ways to do this, but here's a simple example I threw together and tested. Instead of this:

```
<img src="image001.jpg" />
<img src="image002.jpg" />
<img src="image003.jpg" />
<img src="image004.jpg" />
<!-- Etc etc etc -->
```

You could do this:

```
<div id="imgsGoHere">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function crossBrowserEventAttach(objectRef, eventName, functionRef)
    {
        try {
            objectRef.addEventListener(eventName, functionRef, false);
        }
        catch(err) {
            try {
                objectRef.attachEvent("on" + eventName, functionRef);
            }
            catch(err2) {
                // event attachment failed
            }
        }
    }


    function addImageToPage()
    {
        var newImageElement = document.createElement("img");
        newImageElement.src = imageArray[nextImageNumber];

        var targetElement = document.getElementById("imgsGoHere");
        targetElement.appendChild(newImageElement);

        nextImageNumber++;

        if (nextImageNumber < imageArray.length) {
            crossBrowserEventAttach(newImageElement, "load", addImageToPage);
            crossBrowserEventAttach(newImageElement, "error", addImageToPage);
        }
    }

    var nextImageNumber = 0;

    var imageArray = new Array();
    imageArray[imageArray.length] = "image001.jpg";
    imageArray[imageArray.length] = "image002.jpg";
    imageArray[imageArray.length] = "image003.jpg";
    // .
    // .
    // .
    // Snip hundreds of rows
    // .
    // .
    // .
    imageArray[imageArray.length] = "image999.jpg";

    addImageToPage();
</script>
```

Each image is added to the page only after the previous image loads (or fails to load). If your browser is timing out, I think that will fix it.

Of course, the problem might actually not be a timeout, but rather that you're running out of memory/system resources and IE is giving up. Or there might be an IE DOM limitation like Sra said.

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know that one +1

Comment: I don't think it's a memory/resource issue because it works fine in Firefox.  I will give you lazy load suggestion a shot.

Comment: IE 6-8 does not use memory and resources as efficiently as Firefox or other modern browsers.  You will often have bottlenecks in IE that do not occur elsewhere.

Comment: @Joshua, first of all, thanks for the suggestion.  While trying to implement this I figured out at least part of the problem.  For some reason, IE is shifting into compatibility mode mid-page load.  Our security check was detecting that as a different browser than was logged in with and killing the session.  However, correcting for that still didn't completely fix the problem.  IT loads a good 50% more images but it is still dying before all images are loaded.

Comment: @Kevin - Hmm... I'm not sure what else to suggest. Are you sure it's not a resource issue? As Peteorpeter mentioned, IE is often less efficient than other browsers and may hit its limits earlier. Can you test with simpler images (maybe 2-color GIFs instead of full-color JPEGs), or with a shrunk copy of your images (create a scaled down copy at 50% size for testing purposes) and see if it loads more images? If it does, you're probably running into a resource limitation, and there might not be a work-around for that.

Comment: @Joshua, no, I'm not sure at all.  The opposite actually.  I'm becoming more convinced it is some sort of resource issue with IE. I think I might upgrade to IE9 and see if that fixes the issue or not.  Even if it does, I have to support IE7 and higher, so I'll have to figure something out, but at least I'll know.

Comment: @Kevin - A couple other things you could try (and I'm just throwing ideas at the wall here): Write a script that merges images server-side and serve a composite image to the browser so that there's fewer images on the page. Or perhaps just make the user print one page at a time ie. "Print this page, and then click 'next' to go to the next page to print".

Comment: This is the correct answer. Here's the problem-- HTTP requests have a connect timeout; but there's also a connection limit. When a HTTP request is sent by the browser, the countdown starts. If the request doesn't actually complete (because it's stuck waiting for a free connection) before the timeout, it's aborted. The problem is somewhat mitigated in later versions by having a higher connection limit.

Answer (score 2):

No final solution, but some hints...
I think the ie Dom hangs up. I,ve seen this in other cases. I needed simply to show the images and used a js which loads the image the time they came into focus, but that want work if you directly hit print I think. Can you use the new css ability to store imagedata directly instead of links. That should solve your problem. I am not quite sure but I think it is supported since ie 7

Comment: I'm not the greatest with css but I will check out your suggestions.  Unfortunately I don't think I can store the images for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have to work around the IE setting, the easiest way to do it is simply not showing images that are not loaded or replacing them with a default image:

**your html:**

```
<img src="http://domain.com/image.jpg" />
```

**your js:**

```
$('img').load(function(){

    // ... loaded  

}).error(function(){

    // ... not loaded, replace
    $(this).attr('src','/whatever/default.jpg');

    // ... not loaded, hide
    $(this).hide();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a problem with microsoft. Unfortunately, this is a setting that would have to be changed on every single computer, as there is no remote way to alter it. To change it on your computer, try opening regedit and adding the **RecieveTimeout DWORD with a Value of (#of minutes)*6000.**    Hope this helps-CodeKid1001

**Edit:** Sorry about that, I forgot to put in the file path:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings

Answer (score 1):

I used something similar to laod HD pictures as a background using ASP Pages

But i used jQuery to handle the images and its loading. This is a sample for 1 image but with a bit of tweaking you can load dynamically

```
myImage = new Image();
        $(myImage).load(function () 
              {
               $(this).hide(); //Stops the loading effect of large images. can be removed
               $('.csBackground li').append(this); //Append image to where you need it
               $(myImage).show();
              }).attr('src', settings.images[0]) //I pass an array from ASP code behind so 0 can be 'i'
                .error( function { checkImages(); } ) //try and relaod the image or something?
```

So instead of changing the timeout- just try and reload the images on error.

Otherwise i only found a solution that is client specific (HTTP Timeout)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827