# Why I am unable to render this image in my ASP.NET Core website?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Why I am unable to render this image in my ASP.NET Core website? Most of the time it is only partially rendered, I mean it is truncated at some point at a percent of full height.

View:

```
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home")">
```

Controller:

```
    public FileContentResult GetImage()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(...);

        var file = File(bitmap.ToByteArray(), "image/png");

        bitmap.Dispose();

        return file;
    }
```

**EDIT:** I've also tried to convert it to PNG using https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517974/261010 and there is no improvement.

**EDIT2:** Another test:

```
    public FileContentResult GetImage()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(...);

        byte[] result = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            result = stream.ToArray();
        }

        var file = File(result, "image/png");

        bitmap.Dispose();
        
        return file;
   }
```

**EDIT3:** The image size is 970x750 pixels, with a smaller size it renders correctly.

Comment: ...you **do** know the difference between a Win32 BMP compared to a PNG, right?

Comment: changing to `"image/bmp"` does not help at all... Should I convert to PNG?

Comment: Probably because bitmap is disposed before it's fully written to response.

Comment: @AlekseiPetrov there is `ToArray` so dispose should not be that relevant.

Comment: How exactly are you creating the bitmap? Can you please provide a [mre]? Have you checked that everything is actually added or in case of streams - flushed?

Comment: Please check the **EDIT2** section.

Comment: This still is not a [mre] and does not explain how do you create the bitmap.

Comment: @abenci Also how big is that image? I'm guessing the browser is retrieving actual content type from response headers. Are you experiencing the same issue with other images?

Comment: 970x750 pixels. If I reduce the image size to 100x100 it always renders correctly.

Comment: Thats the real question. You should be asking "why the image is not rendered if the size is bigger?" its rendering for 100x100!

Comment: I have tested your code with a 1000x1000 bmp image file (5Mb) and worked fine. This does not reproduce the issue. May be if you provide the image itself and browser version. It could be image browser timeout like the reported in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731081/image-load-timeout-in-internet-explorer), a corrupt image, or something else. But it doesn't happen with the provided debugging details.

Comment: The image is generated on the fly, so it can be slow. How do I tell ASP.NET Core to allow more time for the `GetImage()` method to complete? I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: not sure if this helps you, but I use: public async Task<IActionResult> ...  and return memorystream like this:  using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open))
 {
     await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
 }
 memory.Position = 0;
         return File(memory, "image/jpg", filename);

Comment: I did some progress and get here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77514801/should-i-really-need-to-use-a-separate-thread-to-render-this-image-in-asp-net-co

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely with the size of the file. can you share the size of the file in mbs?
There is a default limit of 10 mb for a  ASP.NEt core application.
Either reduce the size of the file or increase trge default limit of the application.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MaxRequestBodySize = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // 100 MB
    });
}
```